# Get text from live preview to php and convert

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have created this live-preview thingy that works perfectly, but new lines and so on doesn't show, and also I have a bb-codes function I would my text to go through. So that text in the textarea `[b]Hello world[/b]` is **Hello world**

This is my code so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="WPcomment" id="WPComment" placeholder="Legg til tekst..."></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="button" name="answer" value="Live-preview" onclick="showDiv()" />
        <div style="display:none;" id="prevCom"></div>
    </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
        var wpcomment = document.getElementById('WPComment');

        wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
            document.getElementById('prevCom').innerHTML = this.value;
        }
        
        function showDiv() {
           document.getElementById('prevCom').style.display = "block";
        }
        
        </script>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mhp57cno/

The php that I use when I output text from my database is this:

```
$htmltext = htmlspecialchars($htmltext);
$htmltext = showBBcodes($htmltext);

echo $htmltext;
```

What I basicly want is the text from `#prevCom` to output as the `$htmltext` from above

Comment: `nl2br` for `#prevCom` when throwing from server side?

Answer (score 1):

Adding **"white-space: pre-line"** in the div style will work.
Here is the edited code. Now its working....

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="WPcomment" id="WPComment" placeholder="Legg til tekst..."></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="button" name="answer" value="Live-preview" onclick="showDiv()" />
        <div style="white-space: pre-line; display:none;" id="prevCom" ></div>
    </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
        var wpcomment = document.getElementById('WPComment');

        wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
            document.getElementById('prevCom').innerHTML = this.value;
        }
        
        function showDiv() {
           document.getElementById('prevCom').style.display = "block";
        }
        
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, the new line is great and all, but from what I said in my question I want to fetch the text that is written in #WPcomment and get it as a php string

Answer (score 0):

For sending data with new line to php you can use nl2br() function.

For example after you post your data to php and when you assign that data to a php variable you can simply add this in your php ...

$comment = nl2br($_POST["WPcomment"]);